# How To Change Pycharms Default Testing Skeleton From Unittest Format to Pytest?

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm, pytest

I'm trying to change from Unittest to PyTests.  After changing the default test runner from Unittests to py.test under Python integration Tools I'm still getting the Unittest skeleton when creating a new test:

Instead of this:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class Test<selected function>(TestCase):
    pass
```

I want it to be this:

```
import pytest

class Test< selected function >:
    def test_<selected function>:
    pass
```

I tried changing the Python Unit Test Code Template under Preferences>Editor>File and Code templates.

No luck.  Where do I change the default testing template?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the best solution I came up with was creating a new template. I called it `Python Test` and the template is as follows.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import pytest


def test():
    pass
```

This speeds up enough my test creation. At some point they will probably add the testing functionality.